# How to show the log4net log in richtextbox in c#

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to show the log4net log data to the RichTextBox ,
but i don't know how to config it,
can somebody help me ?

I can write the log to  a file,
but i don't know how to show  it in a richtextbox.

the log4net version is 2.0.7 ,the newest

Comment: This is not possible out of the box, you need to write your own appender. This question will help you by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114614/configuring-log4net-textboxappender-custom-appender-via-xml-file

Comment: En,thanks. I will try to write a new appender by myself.